# Serializable class not considering string property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have created a Serializable class with the property

```
[XmlAttribute("ToleranceSign"), DefaultValue("1")]
    public string ToleranceSign { get; set; }
```

When I serialize this class like below

```
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(serializeData.GetType());
            XmlSerializerNamespaces xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
            serial.Serialize(writer, serializeData, xns);
            writer.Flush();
            string serialContent = writer.ToString();
            return serialContent;
        }
```

All the other properties are converted into XML nodes except ToleranceSign. Is there anything wrong i did in declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of `ToleranceSign` is `null`, it will be ignored and not serialized.

If the value of `ToleranceSign` is `"1"`, then the `[DefaultValue("1")]` will cause it to not be serialized. Basically: don't include that attribute if you want it to always be serialized when not `null`.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I have removed the DefaultValue attribute and it worked fine. Since i was assigning "1" to ToleranceSign it was not serializing. I was always thinking that DefaultValue is working like default value in DB (i.e. If no value is assigned, it will add default value)!!

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultValue` attribute will not cause a value assignment. You need to do that trough code. See the [note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx). That being said, string properties should at least be initialized with `String.Empty` in order to get serialized.

Comment: I was assigning "1" to that property.